# Optimizar consulta sql en case Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-18c

espero y me puedan ayudar por favor, lo que pasa es que desarrollé una consulta donde compara un valor de la tabla parametros con otro valor de otra tabla que se llama complemento_pago, pero hay un problema que hice dicha consulta y me sugirieron que la hiciera mas optima por ejm haciendo:
`And Serie = (select case ...... )` en meter los case al select del param 336 pero no entiendo como va la sintaxis, este es mi consulta:

```
SELECT cta_que_factura, tipo_documento,id_estatus, uuid, FECHA_CREACION, NOM_SISTEMA, serie
            from complemento_pago
            where TO_DATE(FECHA_CREACION, 'DD/MM/RRRR') =  TO_DATE(sysdate, 'DD/MM/RRRR')-(select valor from parametros where ID_PARAMETRO =334)
            and nom_sistema = Upper((select valor from parametros where id_parametro =335))  -- -> apartir de aqui abajo se debe de hacer la optimizacion 
             and serie = case WHEN (SELECT valor FROM parametros where id_parametro =336)= '1' then 'PA'
                                         else case WHEN (SELECT valor FROM parametros where id_parametro =336)= '2' then 'PB'
                                    else case WHEN (SELECT valor FROM parametros where id_parametro =336)= '3' then 'PC'
                                            else case WHEN (SELECT valor FROM parametros where id_parametro =336)= '4' then 'PD'
                                                else case WHEN (SELECT valor FROM parametros where id_parametro =336)= '5' then 'PE'
                                                    else case WHEN (SELECT valor FROM parametros where id_parametro =336)= '6' then 'PF'
                                                        else case WHEN (SELECT valor FROM parametros where id_parametro =336)= '7' then 'PG'
                                                            else case WHEN (SELECT valor FROM parametros where id_parametro =336)= '8' then 'PH'
                                                                else case WHEN (SELECT valor FROM parametros where id_parametro =336)= '9' then 'PI'
                                                                end
                                                            end
                                                        end
                                                    end
                                                end
                                            end
                                        end
                                    end
                            end;
```

Podrían por favor ayudarme en como podría cambiarla en como me sugirieron, la verdad soy muy nuevo en esto de sql de este nivel un tanto avanzado, si algo no me di a entender diganmelo por favor ycon gusto les aclararé sus dudas, saludos y quedo al pendiente de sus comentarios.

Comment: Podrías hacer un procedimiento almacenado, guardar el valor del `select valor` en una variable y validarlo.

Comment: Hola buenos dias, el problema es que no puedo crear cosas ya que no tengo privilegios para hacer eso amigo :(

Comment: Qué versión de Oracle estás usando? Recuerda que este tipo de detalles son importantes para que las respuestas sean pertinentes

Comment: Hola, es oracle 18 c

Comment: La sentencia `CASE` sólo tiene dos sintaxis, es claro que estas usando la menos adecuada. Deberías usar algo como `CASE (SELECT ... WHERE id_parametro =336) WHEN = '1' THEN 'PA' ... WHEN = '9' then 'PI' END`

Answer (score 3):

Para comenzar, no necesitas utilizar tantas sentencias `case`, lo cual viene de que introduces una clausula `else` cuando no es necesaria.

La primera simplificación puede ser:

```
SELECT   cta_que_factura
       , tipo_documento,id_estatus
       , uuid
       , FECHA_CREACION
       , NOM_SISTEMA
       , serie
  from complemento_pago
 where TO_DATE(FECHA_CREACION, 'DD/MM/RRRR') =  TO_DATE(sysdate, 'DD/MM/RRRR')-(select valor from parametros where ID_PARAMETRO =334)
   and nom_sistema = Upper((select valor from parametros where id_parametro =335))  -- -> apartir de aqui abajo se debe de hacer la optimizacion
   and serie = case
                 WHEN (SELECT valor FROM parametros where id_parametro =336)= '1' then 'PA'
                 WHEN (SELECT valor FROM parametros where id_parametro =336)= '2' then 'PB'
                 WHEN (SELECT valor FROM parametros where id_parametro =336)= '3' then 'PC'
                 WHEN (SELECT valor FROM parametros where id_parametro =336)= '4' then 'PD'
                 WHEN (SELECT valor FROM parametros where id_parametro =336)= '5' then 'PE'
                 WHEN (SELECT valor FROM parametros where id_parametro =336)= '6' then 'PF'
                 WHEN (SELECT valor FROM parametros where id_parametro =336)= '7' then 'PG'
                 WHEN (SELECT valor FROM parametros where id_parametro =336)= '8' then 'PH'
                 WHEN (SELECT valor FROM parametros where id_parametro =336)= '9' then 'PI'
               end
```

Esto ya hace la sentencia mucho más legible.

Lo siguiente que me viene a la mente, es lanzar una sola vez la consulta de la tabla de parámetros, lo cual debiera estar soportado en la sintaxis, pero no tengo oracle a mano para comprobarlo:

```
SELECT   cta_que_factura
       , tipo_documento,id_estatus
       , uuid
       , FECHA_CREACION
       , NOM_SISTEMA
       , serie
  from complemento_pago
 where TO_DATE(FECHA_CREACION, 'DD/MM/RRRR') =  TO_DATE(sysdate, 'DD/MM/RRRR')-(select valor from parametros where ID_PARAMETRO =334)
   and nom_sistema = Upper((select valor from parametros where id_parametro =335))  -- -> apartir de aqui abajo se debe de hacer la optimizacion
   and serie = case (SELECT valor FROM parametros where id_parametro =336)
                 WHEN '1' then 'PA'
                 WHEN '2' then 'PB'
                 WHEN '3' then 'PC'
                 WHEN '4' then 'PD'
                 WHEN '5' then 'PE'
                 WHEN '6' then 'PF'
                 WHEN '7' then 'PG'
                 WHEN '8' then 'PH'
                 WHEN '9' then 'PI'
               end
```

Esta anterior es mi recomendación, pero no puedo dejar de mencionar que también podrías utilizar una función [`decode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm) en lugar del `case`

```
SELECT   cta_que_factura
       , tipo_documento,id_estatus
       , uuid
       , FECHA_CREACION
       , NOM_SISTEMA
       , serie
  from complemento_pago
 where TO_DATE(FECHA_CREACION, 'DD/MM/RRRR') =  TO_DATE(sysdate, 'DD/MM/RRRR')-(select valor from parametros where ID_PARAMETRO =334)
   and nom_sistema = Upper((select valor from parametros where id_parametro =335))  -- -> apartir de aqui abajo se debe de hacer la optimizacion
   and serie = decode((SELECT valor FROM parametros where id_parametro =336), '1', 'PA', '2', 'PB', '3', 'PC', '4', 'PD', '5', 'PE', '6', 'PF', '7', 'PG', '8', 'PH', '9', 'PI')
```

Comment: Iba por la mitad de la respuesta y vi la tuya igual, así que +1 :P

Comment: @Alfabravo lo mismo pense.

Comment: Buenas tardes @jachhuate, excelente muchas gracias por brindarme opciones, posiblemente ocuparé la segunda opción ya que como tú dices consultar una sola vez la tabla parámetros, de verdad te agradezco mucho y me quedaré con tu respuesta, saludos y te mando las buenas vibras.

Comment: @Alfa, por hoy fui el más rápido, pero no siempre tengo la misma suerte, jeje. Un saludo ;-)